# Docusign eSign: GetDocument request time out

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Recenlty we've been having issues downloading envelope documents.Getting the bellow exception after 6 minutes.

`envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId)`

**DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling GetDocument: The operation has timed out.**

The timeout has set for 10min as bellow,

`var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.Configuration.Timeout = 600000;
 envelopesApi.Configuration.ApiClient.RestClient.Timeout = 600000;//also added this`

But after receive error, when re-trying through the postman is succeeding.

Also this error is intermittent.

Is there anything that we are missing ?

Thanks,
Dula

Comment: is this a very large document?

Comment: it size is around 18mb.

Comment: can you try a smaller document just to establish if that's the reason for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts can occur for a variety of reasons, like internet latency and other TPC/IP issues on the way from DocuSign servers to your box. I would recommend that operations like retrieving large files are done in the background.

You should also suggest you update the SDK to the latest version as some improvements were made in this area.